# Twilio SMS service with callback URL

Tags: twilio

We are using twilio as our SMS service built in C#, Rest API.

I able to send sms successfully but problem is that I set callbackUrl as "URL../SMSLogger" and I am not getting any response from twilio when the the message is sent.

Here SMSLogger is my controller and I made a post method in this controller to log the status of the SMSMessage

Please help... Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

Can you check the Twilio [App Monitor](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/app-monitor) and see if Twilio shows any errors making a request to the URL you've set for your Status Callback URL.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages#post-parameters-optional

Hope that helps.